# Mongoid default scope and includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

If we have two clases with a has_many/belongs_to relation, i.e. User => Projects and in Project class we have `default_scope -> {includes(:user)}` then:

```
project.user # returns X user
project.user = another_user
project.user # returns X user again instead of anoter_user
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: You didn't update the association, its just `assignment`.

Comment: But the assignment is not done, is ignored, if you do the same code without default scope project.user returns another_user